How to achieve such picture effect using python？
I'm drawing a heat distribution map using python. But I found that the pixels of other people’s pictures looked like the first, and mine looked like the second.


It seems that other people's pictures have a cross highlight, but mine does not. I don't know what kind of processing has been done.I sincerely request help !!!
I use plt.imshow() to display the data, but I don’t know what kind of processing is required?

Do any of imshow’s interpolation methods do what you want? https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The first one suggests they are using plt.pcolormesh() with shading="gouraud", rather than plt.imshow().

Thank you for the assistance you provided, but the image effect still isn't quite right. The desired effect feels like bright yellow areas with bright white squares, and red areas with dark squares. Do you have any other suggestions or ideas?

No problem. Other variables to explore, assuming you're using the same colour map, are: vmin= and vmax= for setting the colour range, and maybe also the type of normalisation being used. Usually the image is just scaled to the max/min values, but sometimes they might use log normalisation or something else.
